# How to make perl throw an error for invalid or nonexistent files?

Tags: perl, error-handling, warnings, diamond-operator

Using perl with the -p or -n flags or with the diamond operator on non-existent files will not exit with an error:

```
$ perl -pe '' badfile || echo error
Can't open badfile: No such file or directory.
$
$ perl -ne '' badfile || echo error
Can't open badfile: No such file or directory.
$
$  perl -e 'print while <>' badfile || echo error
Can't open badfile: No such file or directory at -e line 1.
$
```

How can I force perl to throw an error, not just a warning, when given a bad file?

Comment: The other cases are not all that similar to the first.  In the first, there is no script (and the message says that Perl was unable to read a script from the non-existent file).  In the others, there is a Perl script; it is a file that you were expecting the code to operate upon that was not found.  The error messages shouldn't be the same — the problem is different.  Yes, a file is missing in all the cases, but in one case, it is the Perl script file that is missing, whereas in the others it is just a file that Perl was supposed to process as an argument.

Comment: In other words, your code is closer to `perl -ne'print' badfile || echo error!`, which doesn't echo `error!`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for pointing out my error. It seems like perl always ignores bad files (-p, -n, <>). I changed the question to make it clearer. The solution is still useful though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die @_ };` to set the warning handler to throw an error.

```
$ # Put handler code in BEGIN block for -p and -n:
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN{$SIG{__WARN__}=sub{die @_}}' badfile || echo error
Can't open badfile: No such file or directory.
error
$
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN{$SIG{__WARN__}=sub{die @_}}' badfile || echo error
Can't open badfile: No such file or directory.
error
$
$ perl -e '$SIG{__WARN__}=sub{die @_}; print while <>;' badfile || echo error
Can't open badfile: No such file or directory at -e line 1.
error
$
```